# Discord API `Bad Request` when trying to create scheduled event

Tags: api, discord

I am trying to create a [scheduled event](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild-scheduled-event#create-guild-scheduled-event) in Discord [as here](https://gist.github.com/adamsbytes/8445e2f9a97ae98052297a4415b5356f) and getting the error. Could someone help what is the issue? (with `GET` requests everything works)

The URL: [https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/[GUILD](https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/%5BGUILD) ID]/scheduled-events

Headers: `{'Authorization': 'Bot [TOKEN]', 'User-Agent': 'DiscordBot (https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[CLIENT ID]&permissions=8&scope=bot) Python/3.8 aiohttp/3.7.4', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`

The body:
`{"channel_id": [CHANNEL ID], "entity_metadata": null, "name": "Test", "privacy_level": 2, "scheduled_start_time": "2022-09-10T12:42:12", "scheduled_end_time": null, "description": null, "entity_Type": 2, "image": null}`

The error: EXCEPTION: `400`, message: `Bad Request`

Answer (score 0):

please try to have
in User-Agent this:

```
https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[CLIENTID]
```

instead of

```
https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id[CLIENTID]&permissions=8&scope=bot
```

but that would probably give you 401 BAD AUTHORIZATION.

Reading from the body it seems correct, but I cannot tell if you were posting the "scheduled_start_time" right. You can post only time that is ahead of current time. You cannot send and create event's which time has already passed.

In the link you've mentioned the thread on github, I've replied it there and posted my code that work's for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).